# Is there a way to make QSettings generated ini files read only?

Tags: python, qt, qsettings, pyqt6

This is more of a conceptual question than a coding question. I was wondering if there is a way to make an ini file generated by QSettings read-only? I want to limit the user’s ability to edit the contents of an ini file and then import incorrect configuration values. I'm writing my program in PyQt6 and I couldn’t find any read-only functions on the QSettings documentation [website](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsettings.html#compatibility-with-older-qt-versions), so this is a shot in the dark.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Well, you could set the file permission to read only when quitting and then restore it to write when the program starts, but that wouldn't take you very far: making a file as read only won't prevent an user to change its permissions on their own. From what you're asking, it doesn't seem so important to care about this: it's not your responsibility if a user edits a confuration file while they're not supposed to, it's theirs.

Comment: I agree with @musicamante. Making it read-only is a very weak deterrent. If you don't want people messing with it, you could encrypt it, or make it some other non-human-readable format.

Comment: If all your concern is to prevent importing incorrect config values, then I suggest that for every imported value you make a validity check and ignore invalid values and use some default values instead. Problem solved.